# Remove words after particular number using JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I have one `textarea` in which I want to **allow only 30 words** and remove remaining extra words:

```
$("#short_desc").keydown(function(e){

    var d = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
    if(d > 30){
        alert("Only 30 words allowed");
        e.preventDefault();
        // here i want to add logic how to remove words.
        return false;
    }
});
```

I have tried with character count but can't short out this logic. **Can some one provide some hint?**

I have one logic that count spaces and then count character count till 30 spaces and get sub string before that character count.

Comment: Is requirement to 1) retain, or 2) remove punctuation marks ? , for example  `,` , `.` , `;` , `:` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Instead remove the words**; you could assign the 30 first words to the `textarea` value.

The next code works well. The `split()` delimiters are not deleted. I used `capturing parentheses`: any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

> **NOTE:**
>
> You must use double the amount you want to limit. You should use **60**.
>
> I created a "constant" `MAX_WORDS_ALLOW` for make the things simplest.

```
var MAX_WORDS_ALLOW = 30;

// Change, keup and paste event.
$("#short_desc").on("change keyup paste", function(e){   

    var d = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
    if(d > MAX_WORDS_ALLOW ){
        alert("Only "+MAX_WORDS_ALLOW +" words allowed: "+d);
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the 30 first words
        var thirty_Words = $(this).val().split(/(\b[\s,\.-:;]*)/, MAX_WORDS_ALLOW * 2).join("");
        // Here I assign the 30 first words to textarea.
        $(this).val(thirty_Words);

        return false;
    }
    $("#numberWords").html(d);

});

// Initial text, for the JSFiddle example
$("#short_desc").val("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus").change();
```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/xfhoc1gq/2/

Comment: He doesn't only split on whitespace.

Comment: what if someone does a copy paste on your input box.... it will exceed 30... check it...

Comment: i guess the whole question here is about how to validate the input box from exceeding 30 characters...

Comment: @VishalWadhawan Works well ;)

Comment: yes i have tested and i will replace text with 30 characters so there would be not a problem in copy paste